# How to integrate the Google Places API with web application, for the locality suggestion, so that records could be filtered by location later

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am trying to make an application which will let the users search nearby vendors. For that, each vendor registration form will have a textbox where a Vendor can put his address. As I don't have the list of localities to validate against, I am trying to use Googe Places API for locality suggestion.

The locality suggestion textbox in the Vendor registration form will look like the image below:

[locality suggestion textbox in the vendor registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErygL.png)

The user interface to choose the location will look like the image below:
[user interface to choose the location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjxJu.png)

After the locality selection, the user should see only nearby Vendors. The response of the google places API is

```
{
"html_attributions": [],
"results": [
    {
        "formatted_address": "Motera, Ahmedabad, Gujarat, India",
        "geometry": {
            "location": {
                "lat": 23.1036054,
                "lng": 72.6024044
            },
            "viewport": {
                "northeast": {
                    "lat": 23.112303,
                    "lng": 72.611829
                },
                "southwest": {
                    "lat": 23.0824881,
                    "lng": 72.5931459
                }
            }
        },
        "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png",
        "id": "beb375b14ad845f8a22e69c93617bee0256678b9",
        "name": "Motera",
        "photos": [
            {
                "height": 768,
                "html_attributions": [
                    "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102418401241279550190/photos\">Denny 00_</a>"
                ],
                "photo_reference": "CoQBdwAAADhFAFfh71z9-Ezw2FMPN-dfmbVDhp8LFJLVmipB_uiK57ZIHWX9vL6UBxotMee794LGmWy_us0RDS521rblsBJgEWL7Wzmg2_Ni9bVfvRJfE6Cb_wf9hzZqvdQUTozVP5z8FaItU-RHjv7Sz92f_ACk8_CpUsEGfeRHF13uI8j5EhDIB0RXJxrzsLVhUImoqMruGhTvq6O1_ZsOWOJslKCSVsXiU_0_gQ",
                "width": 1280
            }
        ],
        "place_id": "ChIJTxIjdsODXjkRiCMOQDvxt24",
        "reference": "CmRbAAAAfxr_8ylDJoydKhrJFZMQVaziF5T89c-KwrgI95qWKqlwcZddHbuAryoaYMq1Qd17v8d0l9SwM47hwuBiuzPOTAb_9tKYS_0K575oUnMIylmG48cBjzQaDzNbsNOIxPFuEhB3MNrFc3saxfKwtfVGWgbEGhTtyA6ohpXeHhwLQ42PjOiIEOkPxw",
        "types": [
            "sublocality_level_1",
            "sublocality",
            "political"
        ]
    }
],
"status": "OK"
```

}

What should I store in the database from above response so that I can filter records by location? I can split the "formatted_address" key into three and store them in three separate fields in Vendor registration table. But that will be redundant. Or I can store the area, city and state in three separate table and reference the ID. But this seems to be too much work? What is the best way to handle this?

Also, does google allow storing the response data?

Answer (score 0):

You need the geographic coordinates if you want to find "nearby" locations by querying your database.

Last I looked at the Places API TOU, the only data you are allowed to store persistently is the placeId.